# Firestore ExceptionInInitializerError at database modification

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, runtime-error

i tried to use Firestore for my Android application project, but when i run this code, which is basically the documentation code of Firestore:

```
protected Integer sendAllToBack () {
    try {
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("toto", "tata");
        db.collection("users").add(data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

```
    Process: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx, PID: 14497
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.google.firestore.v1.MapValue.newBuilder(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:232)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataReader.parseMap(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:290)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataReader.parseData(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:251)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataReader.convertAndParseDocumentData(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:232)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataReader.parseMergeData(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:87)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.set(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:165)
        at xxxxxxxxxxxxx.MainActivity.sendAllToBack(MainActivity.java:298)
        at xxxxxxxxxxxxx.MainActivity.onDestroy(MainActivity.java:317)
        at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:8078)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1353)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5057)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5101)
        at android.app.servertransaction.DestroyActivityItem.execute(DestroyActivityItem.java:44)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2123)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7710)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get message info for com.google.firestore.v1.MapValue
        at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageInfoFactory.messageInfoFor(GeneratedMessageInfoFactory.java:62)
        at com.google.protobuf.ManifestSchemaFactory$CompositeMessageInfoFactory.messageInfoFor(ManifestSchemaFactory.java:143)
        at com.google.protobuf.ManifestSchemaFactory.createSchema(ManifestSchemaFactory.java:55)
        at com.google.protobuf.Protobuf.schemaFor(Protobuf.java:93)
        at com.google.protobuf.Protobuf.schemaFor(Protobuf.java:107)
        at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.makeImmutable(GeneratedMessageLite.java:171)
        at com.google.firestore.v1.MapValue.<clinit>(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:490)
        at com.google.firestore.v1.MapValue.newBuilder(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:232) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataReader.parseMap(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:290) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataReader.parseData(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:251) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataReader.convertAndParseDocumentData(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:232) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataReader.parseMergeData(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:87) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.set(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:165) 
        at com.bouygues.bysafe.MainActivity.sendAllToBack(MainActivity.java:298) 
        at com.bouygues.bysafe.MainActivity.onDestroy(MainActivity.java:317) 
        at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:8078) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1353) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5057) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5101) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.DestroyActivityItem.execute(DestroyActivityItem.java:44) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2123) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7710) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at com.google.firestore.v1.MapValue.dynamicMethod(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:482)
        at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.dynamicMethod(GeneratedMessageLite.java:252)
        at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.buildMessageInfo(GeneratedMessageLite.java:280)
        at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageInfoFactory.messageInfoFor(GeneratedMessageInfoFactory.java:60)
        at com.google.protobuf.ManifestSchemaFactory$CompositeMessageInfoFactory.messageInfoFor(ManifestSchemaFactory.java:143) 
        at com.google.protobuf.ManifestSchemaFactory.createSchema(ManifestSchemaFactory.java:55) 
        at com.google.protobuf.Protobuf.schemaFor(Protobuf.java:93) 
        at com.google.protobuf.Protobuf.schemaFor(Protobuf.java:107) 
        at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.makeImmutable(GeneratedMessageLite.java:171) 
        at com.google.firestore.v1.MapValue.<clinit>(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:490) 
        at com.google.firestore.v1.MapValue.newBuilder(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:232) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataReader.parseMap(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:290) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataReader.parseData(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:251) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataReader.convertAndParseDocumentData(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:232) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataReader.parseMergeData(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:87) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.set(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:165) 
        at com.bouygues.bysafe.MainActivity.sendAllToBack(MainActivity.java:298) 
        at com.bouygues.bysafe.MainActivity.onDestroy(MainActivity.java:317) 
        at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:8078) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1353) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5057) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5101) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.DestroyActivityItem.execute(DestroyActivityItem.java:44) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2123) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7710) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Has anyone any clue about what i may be doing wrong ?
I tried with
`db.collection("users").document("1").set(data, SetOptions.merge());`
which is the code i wanted to run at the beginning and i had the exact issue.

This code is in the MainActivity of my Android application, and i call it in the onDestroy method.

Comment: How are you implementing the firebase-firestore library? Does your project gather the Prerequisites indicates on the document?https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#prerequisites , Could you share a Minimal, Reproducible Example? https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#prerequisites

Comment: My project gather all the prerequisites, i'm trying to create a minimal example but i don't get this error when i try to. I'm trying to figure another way around because i can't find a way out... I'll keep trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by library version mismatch. Now one can actually go to the trouble of trying to fix this but the docs had a solution which actually works.https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add-sdks

```
dependencies {
  // Import the Firebase BoM
  implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.3.0')

  // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library 
  // dependencies

  // Declare the dependency for the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

  // Declare the dependencies for any other desired Firebase products
  // For example, declare the dependencies for Firebase Authentication and 
  // Cloud Firestore
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
}
```

To learn more about BOM see [Android Bill Of Materials](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/learn-more#bom)